# How to change to the location of ruby gem folder in linux

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

In Linux there is folder `~/.gems` in my home. I want to move it to `/opt/Ruby`.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of tweaking both `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` I would go with producing a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /opt/Ruby ~/.gems
```

That way physically everything is located under `/opt`, while the system/ruby/anything finds gems under the default location.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `GEM_HOME` environment variable to the location where you want gems to install (e.g. `/opt/Ruby`), and then move any existing ones there.

If you're on Linux/UNIX, you'll want to update GEM_HOME in your `.profile` or similar.

Comment: You may want to modify `GEM_PATH` as well; `GEM_PATH` is where gems should be found by Ruby, `GEM_HOME` is where they will be installed.